apt upgrade of "shim-signed" package fails, error shows "special device does not exist" but I haven't changed any drives!
I'm working via SSH (no gui) on an Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS server on a hosted VM. An update to the shim-signed package (to 1.51.4+15.8-0ubuntu1) consistently fails with the error

Setting up shim-signed (1.51.4+15.8-0ubuntu1) ... mount:
/var/lib/grub/esp: special device
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c2975c86d58beaecefea23c29f2d-part1 does not
exist.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess
returned error exit status 32
Errors were encountered while
processing:  shim-signed needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has
failed

This then exits the whole update process.
The error message is correct that /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c2975c86d58beaecefea23c29f2d-part1 does not exist, but it never has, to my knowlegde.
If I grep for this file path string, to find where it may be configured, I only see one result in a config file, which is in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat:
Name: grub-efi/install_devices
Template: grub-efi/install_devices
Value: /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c2975c86d58beaecefea23c29f2d-part1
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-amd64, grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/sda1 (1073 MB; /boot/efi) on 53687 MB Virtual_disk
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c2975c86d58beaecefea23c29f2d-part1

fstab shows that the boot/efi location is: /dev/disk/by-uuid/D379-891B /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
blkid shows that this device is indeed mounted at /dev/sda1 but the "value" and "raw_choices" settings in the config.dat file seem to be incorrect about the path by ID to the device.
I don't usually play with the debconf settings (and I have never changed this value) so I would like to ask more experienced people whether this setting for grub-efi/install-devices is likely to be the cause of my problem and would correcting the path /dev/disk/by-id/scsi-36000c2975c86d58beaecefea23c29f2d-part1 to /dev/disk/by-uuid/D379-891B likely solve this problem?

Take a look at the answer in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203528/errors-grub-efi-amd64-signed-shim-signed

I am seeing the same thing on multiple machines.... the given disk ID is a partial match for an existing disk, but the prefix differs.

@david I'm not sure how that link matches this problem?

I cloned my previous SSD onto a new one, but got the same error as you. I found the solution here (2nd answer): https://askubuntu.com/a/1276122/1923843 After I applied the flags apt started working again!

In my case it turned out that during the install, some udev rules were present that we removed after the install. So the name of the disk "changed". I replaced it with the name that the installer put into the fstab, /dev/disk/by-uuid/ABCD-1234.

I'm seeing the following error on a cloud VM.
Setting up shim-signed (1.51.4+15.8-0ubuntu1) ... Unknown device "/dev/disk/by-id/*": No such file or directory
The VM is starting from an image that was created a couple of months ago. The image has shim-signed 1.51.3+15.7-0ubuntu1 installed.

After a bunch of trial and error, the only working solution that I found was:

Check what the current drive mounted on /boot/efi is:

cat /etc/fstab | grep efi

Output:
/dev/disk/by-uuid/D123-4355C /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1


Manually modify the value for grub-efi/install_devices found in /var/cache/debconf/config.dat so it shows the current device path by id, found above.

Name: grub-efi/install_devices
Template: grub-efi/install_devices
Value: /dev/disk/by-uuid/D123-4355C
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-amd64, grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/sda1 (1073 MB; /boot/efi) on 53687 MB Virtual_disk
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-uuid/D123-4355C

Then run apt upgrade to (successfully) complete the upgrades.
I have read in many places that manually modifying the debconf file is a bad idea, but it's the only solution I found that allowed my system to successfully complete its package upgrades.
