dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure), /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /xxx does not exist
an auto update of my server failed and I found this error in the log:
Setting up shim-signed (1.51.4+15.8-0ubuntu1) ...
mount: /var/lib/grub/esp: special device /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol03d89b2c32d75dfae-part15 does not exist.
dpkg: error processing package shim-signed (--configure):
 installed shim-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 32

I guess the problem is related to this case, but its strange, I didn't change any volume:
Error upgrading grub-efi-amd64-signed - special device [old SSD] does not exist
User plaisthos recommend to edit this cache file:
/var/cache/debconf/config.dat

and to run
sudo dpkg --configure -a

But what's exactly should be edited? And is it save to reboot the system in this state or could this even solve the problem?
Unfortunately the problem occurred on a live system and I want to be very cautiousness to prevent any down times.
My System:
AWS EC2 Server instance, running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and Plesk

sudo lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
loop0          7:0    0  21.8M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7984
loop1          7:1    0  21.9M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/7994
loop2          7:2    0  49.1M  1 loop /snap/core18/2810
loop3          7:3    0  49.1M  1 loop /snap/core18/2826
loop4          7:4    0  59.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/2267
loop5          7:5    0  59.8M  1 loop /snap/core20/2321
loop6          7:6    0  77.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/28384
loop7          7:7    0  77.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/29353
loop8          7:8    0  33.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21467
loop9          7:9    0  33.7M  1 loop /snap/snapd/21761
nvme0n1      259:0    0   512G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1  259:1    0 511.9G  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p15 259:2    0    99M  0 part /boot/efi

sudo df -h
Filesystem       Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/root        496G  375G  122G  76% /
tmpfs             31G     0   31G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             13G  1.1M   13G   1% /run
tmpfs            5.0M   28K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
efivarfs         128K  3.3K  125K   3% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p15   98M  6.3M   92M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs            6.2G  4.0K  6.2G   1% /run/user/1000

part of the /var/cache/debconf/config.dat
Name: grub-efi/install_devices
Template: grub-efi/install_devices
Value: /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol03d89b2c32d75dfae-part15
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-arm64, grub-pc
Flags: seen
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/nvme0n1p15 (103 MB; /boot/efi) on 68719 MB Amazon Elastic Block Store
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol09ffbe328bafbd0eb-part15

Name: grub-efi/install_devices_disks_changed
Template: grub-efi/install_devices_disks_changed
Value: /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol03d89b2c32d75dfae-part15, /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol049f91243e2980923-part15
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-arm64
Variables:
 CHOICES = /dev/nvme0n1p15 (103 MB; /boot/efi) on 549755 MB Amazon Elastic Block Store
 RAW_CHOICES = /dev/disk/by-id/nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol049f91243e2980923-part15

Name: grub-efi/install_devices_empty
Template: grub-efi/install_devices_empty
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub-efi/install_devices_failed
Template: grub-efi/install_devices_failed
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub-efi/partition_description
Template: grub-efi/partition_description
Owners: grub-common, grub-efi-arm64
Variables:
 DEVICE = /dev/nvme0n1p15
 DISK_MODEL = Amazon Elastic Block Store
 DISK_SIZE = 549755
 PATH = /boot/efi
 SIZE = 103

Name: grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline
Template: grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline_default
Template: grub2/kfreebsd_cmdline_default
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/linux_cmdline
Template: grub2/linux_cmdline
Value: 
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/linux_cmdline_default
Template: grub2/linux_cmdline_default
Value: quiet splash
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/no_efi_extra_removable
Template: grub2/no_efi_extra_removable
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/unsigned_kernels
Template: grub2/unsigned_kernels
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/unsigned_kernels_title
Template: grub2/unsigned_kernels_title
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

Name: grub2/update_nvram
Template: grub2/update_nvram
Value: true
Owners: grub-efi-arm64

cat /etc/fstab
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /        ext4   discard,errors=remount-ro       0 1
LABEL=UEFI      /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0 1
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0

sudo parted -l
Model: Amazon Elastic Block Store (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 550GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
15      1049kB  105MB  104MB  fat32              boot, esp
 1      106MB   550GB  550GB  ext4


EDIT
As suggested by David DE, I've looked into this thread:
Error processing package shim-signed
I'm not an expert, but imo my problem is of a different nature. To me it looks like that there is an issue with the disk id (error: "does not exist") for the mounting point /boot/efi which changes for some reason.
In the cache file (/var/cache/debconf/config.dat) I see:
nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol03d89b2c32d75dfae-part15
vs
nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol09ffbe328bafbd0eb-part15
vs
nvme-Amazon_Elastic_Block_Store_vol049f91243e2980923-part15

How can I figure out the correct id and how to fix the setup?
Can I just delete the quoted part of the cache file (/var/cache/debconf/config.dat) and regenerate it with the updated/corrected disk id?
EDIT:
This worked for my case as well (Error upgrading grub-efi-amd64-signed - special device [old SSD] does not exist)
echo PURGE | debconf-communicate grub-common
echo PURGE | debconf-communicate grub-pc
dpkg --configure -a


This question is similar to: Error processing package shim-signed. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hey @DavidDE, thanks for your reply. I cheked the your suggested thread, but I think there is on other issue in my case, see the edit in my original question

This worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/1469488/513681

Thanks @NikhilOwalekar, worked for me as well

This question is similar to: Error upgrading grub-efi-amd64-signed - special device [old SSD] does not exist. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
